# Can't activate python virtual environment on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, python, virtualenv

I have created virtual environment from my MacBook with `python3.9`. Then I've tried to activate that environment from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS subsystem on Windows 10 but could not succeed. There initially exists ython 3.8 on Ubuntu. I downloaded `python3.9` with

```
$ apt install python3.9
```

Then I changed default python3 version with

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 1
```

When I tried to activate my virtual environment with

`$ source venv/bin/activate`,  I got following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File 
"/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound   File 
"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-
packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", 
line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
-bash: venv/bin/activate: line 4: syntax error near unexpected 
token `$'{\r'' 'bash: venv/bin/activate: line 4: `deactivate () {
```

When I type

```
$ python3 -m venv venv --without-pip --system-site-packages
```

in another folder, it creates virtual environment with following error:

```
Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 
'/mnt/c/Users/Emre/Documents/denemedir/venv/bin/activate'
```

I can activate that environment. However, why I can't activate virtual environment that I've created from MacBook?

Comment: I wouldn't expect python environments to be cross compatible in this way.  They can / do contain compiled binaries so moving them onto a completely different OS is unlikely to work well.

Comment: I see two errors, one python one bash.  The bash error looks like something has been edited in windows.  There's an invisible character (carriage return AKA `\r`) on line 4.  Possibly other lines as well.  You can use the command `dos2unix` to strip them off.  The python error is less obvious `No module named 'apt_pkg'`.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I did what you said about `dos2unix` and I achieved activating virtual environment but when I tried to run `server.py` it didn't recognized Flask module. I reinstalled with `pip3` and eventually it installed flask to outside the scope of virtual environment.